# Problem in installing pandas with python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.9, botocore

Here is the final stack trace. I was having problem with botocore and boto3, when I changed version for botocore, pandas error popped up. Please help.

```
pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx:592:15: Assignment to a read-only property
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
    json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return hook(config_settings)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wx42dtie/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wx42dtie/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wx42dtie/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
    super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wx42dtie/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 757, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 542, in maybe_cythonize
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wx42dtie/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1134, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wx42dtie/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1301, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx
[end of output]
```

First I was getting this error when moved to python 3.9 from 3.

'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren'

```
botocore/parsers.py in _replace_nodes at line 434

                "invalid XML received:\n%s" % (e, xml_string))
        return root
    def _replace_nodes(self, parsed):
        for key, value in parsed.items():
            if value.getchildren():
                sub_dict = self._build_name_to_xml_node(value)
                parsed[key] = self._replace_nodes(sub_dict)
            else:
                parsed[key] = value.text
        return parsed
```

When I tried to change botocore version I am facing issue with pandas, mentioned above